# Change size of FX Dialog while it is showing

Tags: layout, javafx, dialog, resize, size

While converting an application from Swing to FX, I came across a dialog that adds/removes fields from a dialog based on a ChoiceBox selection.  I have not been able to figure out how to force the dialog to resize once the new fields get added/removed.  Am I missing something?

Comment: If it is a Window try window.sizeToScene()

Comment: `getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();` Worked like a charm!  Only issue is that it does not take the title of the window into account when sizing.

Comment: Any suggestions on making sure the dialog takes the title's width into account when sizing?

Comment: I don't think there is such a feature.